# div fade out and next div slideUp

Tags: jquery

There are 3 divs with a button that makes current div fade out.

How to slideUp the next div bellow after current div is faded out?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/fs1rnydc/8/)**

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".panel").fadeOut(400);
    $(".this-message").delay( 400 ).fadeIn(400).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
    $(this).parent().next(".panel").slideUp(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) callback functions:

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {

    $(this).closest(".panel").animate({opacity: 0}, 500).slideUp(2000, function() {
        $(".this-message").fadeIn(400, function() {
            $(this).delay(900).fadeOut(400);
        });

    });

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fs1rnydc/9/)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the

```
.fadeOut( "slow", function() { 
    //slide up in here
};
```

Hope this helps

For completeness

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".panel").fadeOut(400, function(){
        $(".this-message").fadeIn(400).delay(900).fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(this).parent().next(".panel").slideUp(2000);
        });  
    });  
});
```

Truez